# I cannot write any code in my Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, html, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I cannot write any code on my VSC. I have followed all advices for this problem from original website, but they didn't allow me to solve the problem.

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc*

I have tried the following changes in VSC:

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/*/**": true
  }
```

And also my watches are already:

`max_user_watches=524288`

I have 64 bit computer. Please help me.

[Visual Studio Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBCOt.png)

Answer (score 0):

The following two steps solved the issue on Ubuntu for me:

**1.Delete the application from the machine.**

> Once I re-installed VSC again, I noticed that hidden folders with default settings from previous installation remained and were causing issues. To see these folders, one must enable 'show hidden folders and files' setting.

**2.I delete `.config` and `.vscode` hidden configuration folders.**

[Folders to delete - Ubuntu OS Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gIDd.png)

[How to show hidden files - Ubuntu OS Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85xwP.png)